# How to apply multiple elements to a single style in CK Editor

Tags: class, styles, ckeditor, multiple-instances

I have searched everywhere and can not seem to find an answer to my problem. To apply a single element to a single style in the ckconfig.jsp file you simply use:

> {name: 'Header 1', element: 'h1', attributes: {'class' :
>   'template_header_1'}},

This apply's the class **template_header_1** to the element **h1**

I am trying to apply a single style to both the li and ul elements. I want something like this:

> {name: 'Special List',
>   {element: 'ul', attributes: {'class' :'ul_class'}},
>   {element 'li',attributes: {'class':'li_class'}}},

In this hypothetical syntax 
**ul** has the class **ul_class** and
**li** has the class **li_class**

This would allow me to apply a single class and have 2 separate classes apply to separate elements with one declaration rather than 2 separate ones. Is this possible?

Comment: This is the first time I have heard of applying an element to a style, what does that mean?

Comment: It is hard at least for me to understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to force all `h1`, `ul` and `li` elements to have a specific class? I this for postprocessing or preprocessing CKEditor data? Are you trying to insert or edit data within CKEditor? Are you trying to filter something? I could just be clueless and have no idea what the java connector does too :)

Comment: The first one is a valid fuction in the ckconfig.jsp file. What I am trying to do is build a style that I can apply to a list containing both **li** and **ul** elements. I can apply a style to **ul** and than apply a different style to **li**, but I'm just trying to simplify it so I can apply one style to a list.

Comment: Ahh now I get it, you are trying to add something to the styles dropdown. I didn't understand that at first. Yeah, no clue.

Comment: Ya I probably should have specified that. haha

Answer (score 1):

I thought I tested and tried my original suggestion, but I apparently did not. I can not reproduce this actually producing a useful result.

The only workaround we found was using the templates plugin to use that to insert more than just one tag of code on demand. Which, obviously, has the downside that you can't add tags to text you have already written; only insert new empty templates, then moving/copy-pasting the text into the template.

I do not have a quick, turn-key solution. The closest idea to make it work was enhancing the styles plugin to accept a "children" parameter so you can nest style definitions, approaching something along the idea of [Angular JS's](http://angularjs.org/) transclusion in directives.

---

**Original answer:**

The closest thing I could find to enabling this is something [mentioned in their forums](http://ckeditor.com/comment/46642#comment-46642). They suggested adding an "initial" attribute, as in:

```
'my nested style': { 
    Element : 'div',
    Attributes : { 
        'class' : 'infobox',
        'Initial' : '<h4>header</h4><p>text</p>'
    } 
}
```

Comment: Did you test that? the post in the forum was a suggestion about what that user would like, not an answer about how to make it work

Comment: @AlfonsoML I thought I did, but when trying it again I could not reproduce it. I updated the answer. Sorry for the false alert!